# Reference a cell using variables for both the column and row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put a value into a cell. I reference the cell using a variable for both the row and the column.

I tried:

```
Dim rowCounter As Long, columnCounter As Long

rowCounter = 18
columnCounter = 10

Range(Columns(columnCounter) & rowCounter).Value = "Did this work?"
```

I get a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel) of the Range object, not the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel). For J18:

```
Dim rowCounter As Long, columnCounter As Long

rowCounter = 18
columnCounter = 10

with worksheets(1)
    .Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Value = "Did this work?"
end with
```

You should really start getting into the practice of providing proper parent worksheet references.

Comment: I am always happy to learn. When you say proper parent worksheet references do you mean something to the effect of adding 
Sheets(1).Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Value = "Did this work?"

Comment: Yes. My own coding style leans to With ... End With blocks like the [edit] above. In situations where there are commonly more than a single workbook open, a parent workbook reference is preferred as well.

Comment: Note the `.` in `.Cells` that states that the cell belongs to the worksheet referenced in the With ... End With.

Comment: That's really cool, I will run with that moving forward. Thanks!